# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on bool

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql

Estoy con un programa en PHP donde tengo que hacer un log-IN, y a la hora de hacer un registro me da un error. Añado que tengo un try catch al principio del todo.

```
$hash_password= hash('sha256',$password); //Encriptar la contraseña con hash
    $query="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Email = :mail AND Pw=:hash_password";
    $stmt = $connexio->prepare($query);
    $stmt=$connexio->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $stmt->bindParam(":mail", $mail);
    $stmt->bindParam(":hash_password", $password);
    //$stmt->execute(array(':mail'=>$mail,':hash_password'=>$hash_password));
    $stmt->execute();
    $count=$stmt->rowCount();// Si existe devolvemos un true y asingamos la session
    $data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //guardamos en la variable data nuestro usuario su ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás fastidiando a la variable `$stmt` en esta línea:

```
$stmt=$connexio->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

debido a que `setAttribute()` devuelve un booleano. Para apagar las preparaciones emuladas basta con que hagas esto:

```
$connexio->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

O que los pases como un array en el constructor que crea la conexión (esto sería lo más recomendable).

Por lo pronto, tu código debería quedar corregido así:

```
$hash_password= hash('sha256',$password); //Encriptar la contraseña con hash
$query="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Email = :mail AND Pw=:hash_password";
$stmt = $connexio->prepare($query);
$connexio->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt->bindParam(":mail", $mail);
$stmt->bindParam(":hash_password", $password);
$stmt->execute();
$count=$stmt->rowCount();// Si existe devolvemos un true y asingamos la session
$data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //guardamos en la variable data nuestro usuario su ID
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaste bastante. A parte de eso falle en la comillas del bindParam.